# Create Lead/Opportunity on Odoo CRM via API and Zapier

Tags: json, odoo, webhooks, zapier

I'm trying to get Zapier working and sending a webhook request to Odoo to create a new lead/opportunity when Zapier fetches it from Facebook Ads.

I don't use Zapier's pre-built automation because it has some data gaps that I can't send like Campaign, Source, and Notes. I would like to use Webhooks for a more complete experience.

I admit I'm not a Webhook/API expert and I took a look at the documentation ([here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/reference/external_api.html)) but I can't get it to work so I need help with this.

The only thing I get working well is an authentication request via ".../web/session/authenticate" url with these params:

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0", "params": {
 "db": "db_name",
 "login": "login",
 "password": "psw"
 }
}
```

but I don't know how to continue and what parameters to use to create a new lead.

Answer (score 0):

You should start reviewing the documentation around external api

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/external_api.html#create-records

After that to know what fields you need to pass to the `crm.lead` create you could inspect the installed modules extensions to `crm.lead` model using the technicals menu to show the model fields and match the data you have in Zappier with the fields on the `crm.lead` model

Comment: Hi aekis.dev,
Thanks for your time. Actually I spent a lot of time testing things with documentation but the problem is I'm still not understanding "how to start" doing this. I mean, starting from the webhook request on Zapier: what is the URL, what is the syntax I should use to write data etc.. I just need the imput to start, after that I can understand what data fields use to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: It's a matter of getting your hands dirty with everything available to get your thing done. You could create a new controller for the task or you could even directly get the Facebook ads into Odoo doing the same thing that Zappier or do the xmlrpc integration that you are trying to do. If you need you could hire someone to make it easy to get this integration. Send me an email if you want this